# What is the difference between addFirst and addLast in Deque interface

Tags: java

They seem like behaving in the same way, throwing out the elements in a LIFO pattern.

```
   Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
       stack.addFirst(i);
   }
   while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
       System.out.print(stack.removeFirst()+",");
   }
```

Prints out : 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,

```
   Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
       stack.addLast(i);
   }
   while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
       System.out.print(stack.removeLast()+",");
   }
```

Prints out : 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,

Comment: "throwing out the elements in a LIFO pattern." that's because you're taking out the last thing you added in both cases: addFirst/removeFirst and addLast/removeLast.

Answer (score 1):

addFirst in deque means that it will be adding every element at the first position like:
lets say there is a variable named "number" and number has 3 elements in it:

```
number = [10,9,8]

// if i add 7 in it
number = addFirst(7)
```

output will be like [7,10,9,8]
and same in addLast it will add element at the last of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It's is due to your print method being different.

```
stack.removeFirst()
// ...
stack.removeLast()
```

On the first case you print them from first to last
On the second case you print them from last to first